# Meteor underscore Cannot call method 'exports' of undefined

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, meteor, underscore.js

I tried to use underscore-string-latest package with meteor but while starting I am getting below error:

```
W20140316-01:08:50.265(8)? (STDERR) /Users/test1/.meteor/tools/f3947a4651/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20140316-01:08:50.265(8)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20140316-01:08:50.266(8)? (STDERR)                               ^
W20140316-01:08:50.269(8)? (STDERR) TypeError: Cannot call method 'exports' of undefined
W20140316-01:08:50.269(8)? (STDERR)     at Package (packages/underscore-string-latest/post.js:8)
W20140316-01:08:50.269(8)? (STDERR)     at packages/underscore-string-latest.js:80:4
W20140316-01:08:50.269(8)? (STDERR)     at packages/underscore-string-latest.js:89:3
W20140316-01:08:50.270(8)? (STDERR)     at /private/var/folders/__/74f_y9md49507s3q616snqw00000gn/T/meteor-test-run1no1trz/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:155:10
W20140316-01:08:50.270(8)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20140316-01:08:50.270(8)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/gunjan/.meteor/tools/f3947a4651/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20140316-01:08:50.270(8)? (STDERR)     at /private/var/folders/__/74f_y9md49507s3q616snqw00000gn/T/meteor-test-run1no1trz/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
=> Exited with code: 8
```

Please help in suggesting to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: perhaps the package is not declaring its explicit underscore dependency. You may want to contact the package author or submit a pull request to fix that. You should be looking in package.js which should contain something similar to `Package.on_use(function(api) { api.use('underscore', ['client', 'server']); api.imply && api.imply('underscore', ['client', 'server']); });`

Answer (score 1):

You could try removing the package and just including the library as part of your project. For example create a `lib/underscore-string` folder and put `underscore.string.js` inside there, and it will be accessible on both client and server.